# 2 dimensional Request on Google Analytics API (adveronix-like)

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get the same data from an Adveronix spreadsheets report
using Google Analytics Python API.

[image: target_table_that_i_wanna_copy]

So far I can get all data except for the Account Column (just picture the above table without the Account column), that one I can get the exact same data with the following request:

```
{'reportRequests': [{'viewId': '[ID]', 
                        'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2022-01-01', 'endDate': '2022-01-01'}],
                        "pivots": [{"dimensions": [{"name": 'ga:date'}],
                                    "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:newUsers"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:sessions"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:sessionsPerUser"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:bounces"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:timeOnPage"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:avgSessionDuration"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:PageViews"}
                                                ]
                                   }]
                      }]}
```

It would make sense to me if the following request worked:

```
{'reportRequests': [{'viewId': '118175578', 
                        'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2022-01-01', 'endDate': '2022-01-01'}],
                        "pivots": [{"dimensions": [{"name": 'ga:date'},{"name": "ga:account_name"}],
                                    "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:newUsers"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:sessions"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:sessionsPerUser"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:bounces"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:timeOnPage"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:avgSessionDuration"},
                                                {"expression": "ga:PageViews"}
                                                ]
                                   }]
                      }]}
```

since I'm only adding another dimension (I've tried adding "ga:city" and it worked just fine)
However I get the following error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "Unknown dimension(s) included in pivot: ga:account_name
```

I've tried several variants of the dimension, like: AccountName,ga:account,ga:userId

What am I doing wrong ?

P.s. i've tried other dimensions from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema for curiosity purposes, most of them don't work.

How can I Request to get the same data as the table?
Adveronix seems to do it so easily [image: adveronix_request]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT!
the error was the way I was requesting
it should be something like this:

```
{'reportRequests': [
    {'viewId': *[MY_VIEW_ID]*,
    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2022-06-13', 'endDate': 'yesterday'}],
    "dimensions": [{'name': "ga:date"}, {"name": 'ga:pageTitle'}, {"name": "ga:pagePath"}],
    "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:PageViews"}],
    "dimensionFilterClauses": filters,
    'pageSize': 100000
    }]}
```

no pivots, just dimensions.